# Conflict between support:appcompat-v7:26.+ and firebase-database:16.0.1

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-appcompat

After update to latest SDK firebase to ver. 16.0.1. I always got an error runtime,

here is the log cat

```
log cat 08-15 23:43:24.685 E/AndroidRuntime(16784): `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.krisoft.krsengine-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.krisoft.krsengine-2/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
```

And here is my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.krisoft.krsengine"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1"
        multiDexEnabled true



    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {



    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:+'
    //Firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:+'
    //Design
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
    //Volley
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:+'
    //Shimmer
    compile 'com.romainpiel.shimmer:library:1.4.0@aar'


   }
```

I tried many solution on google but I can't figure it out what exactly the problem, anyone can help me?

Comment: Please add the content of your build.gradle file.

Comment: Upload complete code of radle File

Comment: According to android documentation avoid using **+** in build numbers, always write the complete dependency.
You can check the latest & previous version through this website
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/design/27.1.0

Comment: Sorry for the qustion, I want to build project with min sdk 15 but when I tried to import dependencies firebase core, database, firebase ads, without app compat it run normaly but after I add appcompat-v7, recyclerview-v7, and card view its make over 64k and make error database init provider not found.

Comment: I try using multiDexEnable true but its still error.

Answer (score 0):

Add UI dependency on your gradle . My compile sdk version is 27

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

just add this dependency,

implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

After that i hope i will work well.

Comment: Nope its not solve my problem is too many classes so its must enable multi dex but I still got error

Comment: sent to me all your gradle dependencies i will fix all errors.

Comment: Can you try, my gradle  at my question

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'  .  Your targetSdkVersion 21       change it to 26 or change the support libraries 26 to 21